# Best practises for Python formatting of floats - PEP 3101 and other methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm working with a data set containing lists with 10^5 - 2*10^5 entries, so millions of records.

One of the fields is a float denoting a percentage. I need to convert it on the fly as I slice the list ( `[x:y]` ) showing between 90 - 180 values at a time.

This is my current solution:
`"{:0.2%}".format(float(entry[14]))`

`entry` is one record in a list, which is iterated upon with a `for entry in lstAlist:` construction.

Which gives me a neat % with two decimals precision. This is in line with the PEP 3101 standard (correct me if I'm wrong).

However, is this the fastest way to do this? Can you recommend alternative and faster methods to do this?

The list slicing and output is happening 2 times per minute.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. We need to see what is “entry”. 2. F-strings are faster than format.

Comment: entry is one record in a list, which is iterated upon with a for entry in lstAlist: construction.